# 404 not found error when given enum parameter in URL

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller, view, enums

I want to call a view using an enum as a parameter. I made sure to add a PublicJournalEntries view, but I get a 404 page not found every time I run. I have another controller set up with a GetByEnum method that works perfectly, unsure if there is a silly error I made that Im overlooking.

here is the url Im using "https://localhost:44399/JournalEntries/PublicJournalEntries?PublicOrPrivate=1"

this is the code in the controller calling the view

```
 public ActionResult PublicJournalEntries(PublicOrPrivate publicPost)
        {
            var service = new PublicPostServices();

            var model = service.GetPublicPosts(publicPost);

            return View(model);
        }
```

here is the .GetPublicPosts method

```
 public IEnumerable<JournalEntryListItem> GetPublicPosts(PublicOrPrivate publicPost)
        {
            
            using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var query =
                    ctx
                    .JournalEntries
                    .Where(x => x.PublicOrPrivate == publicPost)
                    .Select(
                         x => new JournalEntryListItem
                         {
                             
                             Tag = x.Tag,
                             Prompt = x.Prompt,
                             Content = x.Content,
                             PhotoUrl = x.PhotoUrl,
                             CreatedUtc = x.CreatedUtc
                         }
                        );
                return query.ToArray();

            }
        }
```

Comment: How you create your url. Do you have a view  or you call from ajax?

Comment: have your tried adding [FromQuery] attribute next to parameter?

Answer (score 1):

you have to fix  your url:

```
https://localhost:44399/JournalEntries/PublicJournalEntries?publicPost=1"
```

and the action too:

```
public ActionResult PublicJournalEntries([FromQuery] PublicOrPrivate publicPost)
```